# Python: Create a Dictionary with key and values from different input

Tags: python, dictionary, web

I have a script that is looking on different webtext URL based on a list of ID.
I want to extract a specific information on each of these text pages (the string after \sC:).
So far I am able to store these strings output in a list, however it is not the best to keep track of the correspondence between the original ID searched and the resulting output.
I would like to make a dictionary instead of a list with the ID searched as a key and the corresponding output as values.

Here is my script so far:

```
import urllib2
import sys
import re

IDlist = ['C9JVZ1', 'C9JLN0', 'C9J872']

URLlist = ["http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"+x+".txt" for x in IDlist]
function_list = []
for item in URLlist:
    textfile = urllib2.urlopen(item)
    myfile = textfile.readlines();
    for line in myfile:
        print "line:", line;
        found = re.search('\s[C]:(.+?);', line);
        if found:
            function = found.group(1);
            function_list.append(function)
```

The output I get is:

```
['cytosol', 'nucleus', 'transcription factor complex']
```

where nothing is found in http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/C9JVZ1.txt

`Cytosol` is found in http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/C9JLN0.txt

and `nucleus`, `transcription factor complex` found in http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/C9J872.txt

The output I'm looking for is something like:

```
{'C9JVZ1':[], 'C9JLN0':['cytosol'], 'C9J872':['nucleus', 'transcription factor complex']}
```

I have tried:

```
if found:
            function = found.group(1);
            function_dic = {item:[function]}
```

but I get this output:

```
>>> function_dic
{'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/C9J872.txt': ['transcription factor complex']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function_dic = {item:[function]}
```

This overwrites the dictionary every loop with just the last entry, to fix that you would do:

```
function_dic[item] = [function]
```

But this would just overwrite the value each time, so you would only have one function, so to fix this you would do:

```
function_dic[item].append(function)
```

However you would need to initialise this outside of the inner for loop:

```
function_dic[item] = []
```

You mentioned you want `ID` not `URL` so you can change your outer for loop to include the ID and use that to construct your dictionary, so putting it all together:

```
function_list = {}
for id, item in zip(IDlist, URLlist):
    function_list[id] = []
    ...
    for line in myfile:
        ...
        if found:
            function = found.group(1)
            function_list[id].append(function)
```

Comment: Am I right to do like this?
because I get an attribute error
"AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'"
Am i doing something wrong?


function_list = {}
for id, item in zip(IDlist, URLlist):
    function_list[id] = {}
    for item in URLlist:
        textfile = urllib2.urlopen(item);
        myfile = textfile.readlines();
        for line in myfile:
            print "line:", line;
            found = re.search('\s[C]:(.+?);', line);
            if found:
                function = found.group(1);
                function_list[id].append(function)

Comment: Sorry, fixed the `function_list[id]` should initialised to a list `[]` not `{}`

Comment: Thanks, no error
But the output is:
{'C9JVZ1': ['cytosol', 'nucleus', 'transcription factor complex'], 'C9J872': ['cytosol', 'nucleus', 'transcription factor complex'], 'C9JLN0': ['cytosol', 'nucleus', 'transcription factor complex']}
It looks like the whole list of results is appended to each key

Comment: Edit sorry i did it wrong now it is working
output:{'C9JVZ1': [], 'C9J872': ['nucleus', 'transcription factor complex'], 'C9JLN0': ['cytosol']}  
Thanks a lot!